# Which of the following field extensions are Galois?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

a) $\mathbb{F}_q \subset \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ where $q$ is a primary number

b) $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$

c) $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, 5^{1/5})$

I know a field extension is Galois iff |Gal(E/F)| = [E:F], but is that the only way to tell?  I can eaisily compute [E:F], but I feel like finding all the automorphisms is a bit annoying.  I know for b it is Galois because be have a theorem about extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ by square roots of distinct primes, but I don't see any other theorems that would apply for a or c.

I added a full attempt in the comments

Comment: Being galois is equivalent to being the splitting field for a certain polynomial (not sure if you have seen this theorem before). Try applying this for a to the polynomial $x^{q^n}-x$. For $c$, does $x^5-5$ have every root in this field?

Comment: @SheelStueber so can you tell me if this is correct? a) is Galois because I have separability by some theorem about finite fields and I have that its normal because when you consider the polynomial $x^{p^n} -x, F_{p_n}$ is the splitting field and since its finite you only need one.  For c), the minimal polynomial $x^2 -5$ doesn't split in $\mathbb{Q}(5^{1/5})$ so its not normal and therefore not Galois

Comment: That must be a typo in your comment: surely you meant to write “For c), the minimal polynomial $x^5-5$ doesn’t…”

Comment: @lubin Yes thank you! I wrote down $x^5$ so must have been a typo but I assume your comment means the rest is ok

Comment: yes you are correct